# Alexa node js (alexa-app-server) response.say not outputting speech

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, alexa-skills-kit

I've been having some trouble trying to output speech after getting data using request-reponse and processing it. For whatever reason in the callback function it wont output the text. The console.log(prompt) works yet it the response.say(prompt).shouldEndSession(false).send() doesn't. If you've any idea it'll be greatly appreciated.

```
test.getNumberStatus(number, function(err, message) {
    console.log("In callback outside if statement");
    if (err == null) {
      console.log(message);
      response.say(message).shouldEndSession(false).send();
    } else {
      console.log("Error");
      rresponse.say(message).shouldEndSession(false).send();
    }
  });

stopInfo.prototype.getStopStatus = function(stopNumber, callback) {
  var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: ENDPOINT + '?stopid=' + stopNumber + '&maxresults=1&format=json',
  json: true
};

requestPromise(options).then(function(stopStatusObject) {
if (true) { // check if error from dublin bus
  console.log(stopStatusObject);

  var template = _.template('busstopinfo <%= error %>');
  var message = template({
      'error': 'test'
  });
  callback(null, message);
}
}).catch(function(err) {
var message = "I didn\'t have data for stop number " + stopNumber;
callback(err, message);
});
};
```

Comment: I found out with a test case that when the request-promise is used it doesnt work but if i take it out it does, I still dont know how to fix it though

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and found out resolve automatically sends your output which works for sync but not for async.  Put add `response.resolve` in your troubled function to see if value is set to true before `send()`.  If it is you already used the promise.  I corrected mine by putting return in front of function name, following Asynchronous Handlers Example section from [here](https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-app/blob/master/README.md#intentrequest.)